# Laravel image embed failure

Tags: php, image, email, laravel, embed

I am having the problem in embeding images, but for the icon that is working fine and display the icon in mail, but for inside the foreach I am having some problem in displaying the images.

This is the shopping cart details I am trying to send for the customer email address! please help me to fix this !

@foreach($products as $item)

```
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <tr>

            <td align="center">
                **<img src="{{ $message->embed('img/tempEng/{!!$item->imgPath]!!}') }}" style="padding:0px; margin:0px" />**
            </td>

            <td align="center">
                {{$item['name']}}
            </td>

            <td>
                <td align="center">{{ $item['quantity'] }}</td>
                <?php $quantity = $quantity + $item['quantity']  ?>
            </td>

            <td align="center">LKR {{$item['price']}}</td>

            <td align="center">{{$item['discount']}}%</td>

            <td align="center"><?php $item['price']=$item['price']*$item['quantity'] - ($item['price']*$item['quantity']*$item['discount'])/100.0 ?>LKR {{$item['price']}}</td>

        </tr>

        <?php $total=$total+$item['price']; ?>
        {{--$i++;--}}
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I don't think that laravel blade echo is nest-able and there is a syntax error too. You could build your string beforehand like `<?php $path='img/tempEng/' . $item->imgPath; ?>`  and use `{!! $message->($path) !!}` instead of the nesting. Furthermore, you probably should use url() helper or its going to depend on the current url/route.

Comment: no embed keyword ?

Comment: my fault, it should be `{!! $message->embed($path) !!}`